# Please return to the payment page and correct the address

Tags: paypal

i have an problem with integration of paypal sandbox for Australia. 
in back end i enabled all tab except billing_phone number. when i click pay now i get following error Please return to the payment page and correct the address. here i am attaching my code. thanks in advance

```
<iframe name="hss_iframe" width="600px" height="600px" style="margin-top:-5px"></iframe>
<form style="display:none" target="hss_iframe" name="form_iframe" method="post" action="https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/acquiringweb">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
  <input type name="subtotal" value="71">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="FK4PGWANVUF9C">
  <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0">
  <input type name="paymentaction" value="sale">
  <input type="hidden" name="template" value="templateD">
  <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="12345">
  <input type="hidden" name="billing_first_name" value="John">
  <input type="hidden" name="billing_last_name" value="Due">
  <input type="hidden" name="billing_address1" value="5 Cromwell St">
  <input type="hidden" name="billing_address2" value="Glen Iris">
  <input type="hidden" name="billing_city" value="Glen Iris">
  <input type="hidden" name="billing_state" value="VIC">
  <input type="hidden" name="billing_zip" value="3146">
  <input type="hidden" name="buyer_email" value="mark@bssound.com.au">
  <input type="hidden" name="billing_country" value="AU">
  <input type name="return" value="https://122.165.58.219/team2/wpp-hosted/receipt_page.html">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.form_iframe.submit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My code wasn't working either, but I didn't have the billing fields which I have now added and it worked.

I didn't have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0">
```

Hope this helps anyone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by adding the same bunch of fields but without "billing_". In your case it will be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John">
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Due">
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="5 Cromwell St">
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="Glen Iris">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="VIC">
<input type="hidden" name="zip" value="3146">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="AU">
```

I don't know whether it's important or not but I also removed both "billing_address2" and "address2".